# I can't get soilgrid image with Python - OWSLib

Tags: python, soilgrids, owslib

I'm trying get an imagen GTIFF with OWSLib in Python but I get error. Would you help me?

Code:

```
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService
wcs = WebCoverageService('http://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/phh2o.map', version='1.0.0')

bbox = (-54.7968690628577, -28.35600162342199, -54.77831702365789, -28.33600341642725)

response = wcs.getCoverage(
    identifier='phh2o_0-5cm_mean', 
    crs='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
    bbox=bbox, 
    resx=250, resy=250, 
    format='GEOTIFF_INT16')

response.read()
```

Output:

> b'\n<ServiceExceptionReport version="1.2.0"\nxmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ogc [http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd">\n](http://schemas.opengis.net/wcs/1.0.0/OGC-exception.xsd%22%3E%5Cn)  msImageCreate(): Image handling error. Attempt to allocate raw image failed, out of memory.\n  \n\n'

Comment: You are exceeding the limits of the server so you will need to request two (or more) smaller images and combine them on your machine

Comment: That bounding box is in the south Atlantic. There are no land masses there, you will just get an empty map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your request, you are working with `EPSG:4326` which is a geographic coordinate system using degrees. The request `resx=250, resy=250` asks for a grid with a resolution of 250 degrees, and the server will try to read all data and make an aggregated grid and reporting an out of memory.

If you try something like `0.001`

```
response = wcs.getCoverage(
    identifier='phh2o_0-5cm_mean', 
    crs='urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
    bbox=bbox, 
    resx=0.001 , resy=0.001, 
    format='GEOTIFF_INT16')
```

You will be more successful obtaining a grid (resolution around 111 meters, depending where you are on the planet).

Comment: Thank you! it worked for me