# Error getting soilgrid image with Python - OWSLib

Tags: python, wcs, soilgrids, owslib

This question is an addition to this [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373455/i-cant-get-soilgrid-image-with-python-owslib). I'm trying to get a SoilGrid GeoTIFF image using OWSLib in python. Here is the script I am running:

```py
from owslib.wcs import WebCoverageService

wcs = WebCoverageService('https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/clay.map', version = '2.0.1')

# comes from my shapefile
bbox = (10.017215784693967, 35.63600166380057, 10.024866939934073, 35.64423653393575)

response = wcs.getCoverage(
    identifier = ['clay_0-5cm_mean'], 
    crs = 'EPSG::4326',
    bbox = bbox, 
    resx = 0.1, resy = 0.1, 
    format = 'image/tiff')
```

And here is the output I get:

```py
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ServiceException                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_1537/4024548350.py in <module>
----> 1 response = wcs.getCoverage(
      2     identifier = [coverage_id],
      3     crs = crs,
      4     bbox = bbox,
      5     resx = 0.01, resy = 0.01,

~/anaconda3/envs/work_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owslib/coverage/wcs201.py in getCoverage(self, identifier, bbox, time, format, subsets, resolutions, sizes, crs, width, height, resx, resy, resz, parameter, method, timeout, **kwargs)
    217         log.debug("WCS 2.0.1 DEBUG: Second part of URL: %s" % data)
    218 
--> 219         u = openURL(base_url, data, method, self.cookies, auth=self.auth, timeout=timeout, headers=self.headers)
    220         return u
    221 

~/anaconda3/envs/work_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/owslib/util.py in openURL(url_base, data, method, cookies, username, password, timeout, headers, verify, cert, auth)
    209 
    210     if req.status_code in [400, 401]:
--> 211         raise ServiceException(req.text)
    212 
    213     if req.status_code in [404, 500, 502, 503, 504]:    # add more if needed

ServiceException: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ows:ExceptionReport xmlns:ows="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0.1" xml:lang="en-US" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/ows/2.0 http://schemas.opengis.net/ows/2.0/owsExceptionReport.xsd">
...
  <ows:Exception exceptionCode="InvalidParameterValue" locator="size">
    <ows:ExceptionText>msWCSGetCoverage20(): WCS server error. Raster size out of range, width and height of resulting coverage must be no more than MAXSIZE=16384.</ows:ExceptionText>
  </ows:Exception>
```

I've tried changing the resolution, I've tried using `height = 100, width = 100` in the parameters, precising a `time = '2013'` argument, but I can't get it to work.

My conda env:

```bash
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                        main
_openmp_mutex             5.1                       1_gnu
affine                    2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
alabaster                 0.7.12             pyhd3eb1b0_0
arrow                     1.2.3            py38h06a4308_0
astroid                   2.11.7           py38h06a4308_0
asttokens                 2.0.8                    pypi_0    pypi
atomicwrites              1.4.0                      py_0
attrs                     22.1.0           py38h06a4308_0
autopep8                  1.6.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1           py38h06a4308_0
binaryornot               0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_1
black                     22.6.0           py38h06a4308_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
boto3                     1.24.91                  pypi_0    pypi
botocore                  1.27.91                  pypi_0    pypi
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h27cfd23_1003
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f8727e_0
ca-certificates           2022.10.11           h06a4308_0
cairo                     1.16.0               h19f5f5c_2
cdsapi                    0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
certifi                   2022.9.24        py38h06a4308_0
cffi                      1.15.1           py38h74dc2b5_0
cfitsio                   3.470                h5893167_7
cftime                    1.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
chardet                   4.0.0           py38h06a4308_1003
charset-normalizer        2.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
click                     8.1.3                    pypi_0    pypi
click-plugins             1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
cligj                     0.7.2                    pypi_0    pypi
cloudpickle               2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
colorama                  0.4.5            py38h06a4308_0
contourpy                 1.0.5                    pypi_0    pypi
cookiecutter              1.7.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
cryptography              38.0.1           py38h9ce1e76_0
curl                      7.84.0               h5eee18b_0
cycler                    0.11.0                   pypi_0    pypi
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0
debugpy                   1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
diff-match-patch          20200713           pyhd3eb1b0_0
dill                      0.3.6            py38h06a4308_0
docutils                  0.18.1           py38h06a4308_3
ecmwf-api-client          1.6.3                    pypi_0    pypi
entrypoints               0.4              py38h06a4308_0
eodag                     2.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
eodag-sentinelsat         0.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
eto                       1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
executing                 1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
expat                     2.4.9                h6a678d5_0
fiona                     1.8.21                   pypi_0    pypi
flake8                    4.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_1
flasgger                  0.9.5                    pypi_0    pypi
flask                     2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
fontconfig                2.13.1               h6c09931_0
fonttools                 4.37.4                   pypi_0    pypi
freetype                  2.11.0               h70c0345_0
freexl                    1.0.6                h27cfd23_0
gdal                      3.4.1            py38h2c27f0e_0
geojson                   2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
geomet                    0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
geopandas                 0.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
geos                      3.8.0                he6710b0_0
geotiff                   1.7.0                hd69d5b1_0
giflib                    5.2.1                h7b6447c_0
glib                      2.69.1               h4ff587b_1
gst-plugins-base          1.14.0               h8213a91_2
gstreamer                 1.14.0               h28cd5cc_2
h5netcdf                  1.1.0                    pypi_0    pypi
h5py                      3.7.0                    pypi_0    pypi
hdf4                      4.2.13               h3ca952b_2
hdf5                      1.10.6               h3ffc7dd_1
html2text                 2020.1.16                pypi_0    pypi
icu                       58.2                 he6710b0_3
idna                      3.4              py38h06a4308_0
imagesize                 1.4.1            py38h06a4308_0
importlib-metadata        5.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
importlib-resources       5.10.0                   pypi_0    pypi
importlib_metadata        4.11.3               hd3eb1b0_0
inflection                0.5.1            py38h06a4308_0
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h06a4308_3561
intervaltree              3.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ipykernel                 6.16.0                   pypi_0    pypi
ipython                   8.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1
isort                     5.9.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
itsdangerous              2.1.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jedi                      0.18.1           py38h06a4308_1
jeepney                   0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
jellyfish                 0.9.0            py38h7f8727e_0
jinja2                    3.1.2            py38h06a4308_0
jinja2-time               0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
jmespath                  1.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
jpeg                      9e                   h7f8727e_0
json-c                    0.13.1               h1bed415_0
jsonpath-ng               1.5.3                    pypi_0    pypi
jsonschema                4.16.0           py38h06a4308_0
jupyter-client            7.4.2                    pypi_0    pypi
jupyter-core              4.11.1                   pypi_0    pypi
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0
kealib                    1.4.14               hb50703a_1
keyring                   23.4.0           py38h06a4308_0
kiwisolver                1.4.4                    pypi_0    pypi
krb5                      1.19.2               hac12032_0
landsatxplore             0.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
lazy-object-proxy         1.6.0            py38h27cfd23_0
ld_impl_linux-64          2.38                 h1181459_1
lerc                      3.0                  h295c915_0
libboost                  1.73.0              h28710b8_12
libclang                  10.0.1          default_hb85057a_2
libcurl                   7.84.0               h91b91d3_0
libdap4                   3.19.1               h6ec2957_0
libdeflate                1.8                  h7f8727e_5
libedit                   3.1.20210910         h7f8727e_0
libev                     4.33                 h7f8727e_1
libevent                  2.1.12               h8f2d780_0
libffi                    3.3                  he6710b0_2
libgcc-ng                 11.2.0               h1234567_1
libgdal                   3.4.1                h05199a0_1
libgfortran-ng            11.2.0               h00389a5_1
libgfortran5              11.2.0               h1234567_1
libgomp                   11.2.0               h1234567_1
libkml                    1.3.0                h7ecb851_5
libllvm10                 10.0.1               hbcb73fb_5
libnetcdf                 4.8.1                h42ceab0_1
libnghttp2                1.46.0               hce63b2e_0
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0
libpq                     12.9                 h16c4e8d_3
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0
libspatialindex           1.9.3                h2531618_0
libspatialite             4.3.0a              hbedb2dc_20
libssh2                   1.10.0               h8f2d780_0
libstdcxx-ng              11.2.0               h1234567_1
libtiff                   4.4.0                hecacb30_0
libuuid                   1.0.3                h7f8727e_2
libwebp                   1.2.4                h11a3e52_0
libwebp-base              1.2.4                h5eee18b_0
libxcb                    1.15                 h7f8727e_0
libxkbcommon              1.0.1                hfa300c1_0
libxml2                   2.9.14               h74e7548_0
libxslt                   1.1.35               h4e12654_0
libzip                    1.8.0                h5cef20c_0
lxml                      4.9.1            py38h1edc446_0
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h295c915_1
markdown                  3.4.1                    pypi_0    pypi
markupsafe                2.1.1            py38h7f8727e_0
matplotlib                3.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
matplotlib-inline         0.1.6            py38h06a4308_0
mccabe                    0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
memory-profiler           0.61.0                   pypi_0    pypi
mistune                   2.0.4                    pypi_0    pypi
mkl                       2021.4.0           h06a4308_640
mkl-service               2.4.0            py38h7f8727e_0
mkl_fft                   1.3.1            py38hd3c417c_0
mkl_random                1.2.2            py38h51133e4_0
multiprocess              0.70.14                  pypi_0    pypi
munch                     2.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
mypy_extensions           0.4.3            py38h06a4308_1
nbclient                  0.5.13           py38h06a4308_0
nbconvert                 6.5.4            py38h06a4308_0
nbformat                  5.5.0            py38h06a4308_0
ncurses                   6.3                  h5eee18b_3
nest-asyncio              1.5.6                    pypi_0    pypi
netcdf4                   1.6.2                    pypi_0    pypi
nspr                      4.33                 h295c915_0
nss                       3.74                 h0370c37_0
numpy                     1.23.4                   pypi_0    pypi
numpydoc                  1.5.0            py38h06a4308_0
opencv-python             4.6.0.66                 pypi_0    pypi
openjpeg                  2.4.0                h3ad879b_0
openssl                   1.1.1s               h7f8727e_0
owslib                    0.27.2                   pypi_0    pypi
p-tqdm                    1.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pandas                    1.5.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pathos                    0.3.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pathspec                  0.9.0            py38h06a4308_0
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003
pillow                    9.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pip                       22.3.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pixman                    0.40.0               h7f8727e_1
pkgutil-resolve-name      1.3.10           py38h06a4308_0
platformdirs              2.5.2            py38h06a4308_0
pluggy                    1.0.0            py38h06a4308_1
ply                       3.11                     py38_0
poppler                   0.81.0               h01f5e8b_2
poppler-data              0.4.11               h06a4308_0
pox                       0.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
poyo                      0.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
ppft                      1.7.6.6                  pypi_0    pypi
proj                      6.2.1                h05a3930_0
prompt-toolkit            3.0.31                   pypi_0    pypi
psutil                    5.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2
pure-eval                 0.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
pycodestyle               2.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyflakes                  2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pygments                  2.13.0                   pypi_0    pypi
pylint                    2.14.5           py38h06a4308_0
pyls-spyder               0.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyparsing                 3.0.9            py38h06a4308_0
pyproj                    3.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
pyqt                      5.15.7           py38h6a678d5_1
pyqt5-sip                 12.11.0          py38h6a678d5_1
pyqtwebengine             5.15.7           py38h6a678d5_1
pyrsistent                0.18.1                   pypi_0    pypi
pyshp                     2.3.1                    pypi_0    pypi
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38h06a4308_0
pystac                    1.6.1                    pypi_0    pypi
python                    3.8.13               h12debd9_0
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-fastjsonschema     2.16.2           py38h06a4308_0
python-lsp-black          1.2.1            py38h06a4308_0
python-lsp-jsonrpc        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
python-lsp-server         1.5.0            py38h06a4308_0
python-slugify            5.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
pytz                      2022.4                   pypi_0    pypi
pyxdg                     0.27               pyhd3eb1b0_0
pyyaml                    6.0              py38h7f8727e_1
pyzmq                     24.0.1                   pypi_0    pypi
qdarkstyle                3.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qstylizer                 0.1.10             pyhd3eb1b0_0
qt-main                   5.15.2               h327a75a_7
qt-webengine              5.15.9               hd2b0992_4
qtawesome                 1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
qtconsole                 5.3.2            py38h06a4308_0
qtpy                      2.2.0            py38h06a4308_0
qtwebkit                  5.212                h4eab89a_4
rasterio                  1.3.2                    pypi_0    pypi
readline                  8.1.2                h7f8727e_1
requests                  2.28.1           py38h06a4308_0
requests-futures          1.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
rope                      0.22.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
rtree                     0.9.7            py38h06a4308_1
s3transfer                0.6.0                    pypi_0    pypi
scipy                     1.9.2                    pypi_0    pypi
secretstorage             3.3.1            py38h06a4308_0
sentinelsat               1.1.1                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                65.5.0           py38h06a4308_0
shapely                   1.8.5.post1              pypi_0    pypi
sip                       6.6.2            py38h6a678d5_0
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
snuggs                    1.4.7                    pypi_0    pypi
sortedcontainers          2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
soupsieve                 2.3.2.post1      py38h06a4308_0
sphinx                    5.0.2            py38h06a4308_0
sphinxcontrib-applehelp   1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-devhelp     1.0.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp    2.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-jsmath      1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-qthelp      1.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml 1.1.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
spyder-kernels            2.3.3            py38h06a4308_0
sqlite                    3.39.3               h5082296_0
stack-data                0.5.1                    pypi_0    pypi
text-unidecode            1.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0
textdistance              4.2.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
three-merge               0.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
tiledb                    2.3.3                h1132f93_2
tinycss                   0.4             pyhd3eb1b0_1002
tinycss2                  1.2.1            py38h06a4308_0
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
tomli                     2.0.1            py38h06a4308_0
tomlkit                   0.11.1           py38h06a4308_0
tornado                   6.2              py38h5eee18b_0
tqdm                      4.64.1                   pypi_0    pypi
traitlets                 5.4.0                    pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         4.3.0            py38h06a4308_0
typing_extensions         4.3.0            py38h06a4308_0
ujson                     5.4.0            py38h6a678d5_0
unidecode                 1.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0
urllib3                   1.26.12          py38h06a4308_0
usgs                      0.3.4                    pypi_0    pypi
watchdog                  2.1.6            py38h06a4308_0
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0
webencodings              0.5.1                    py38_1
werkzeug                  2.2.2                    pypi_0    pypi
whatthepatch              1.0.2            py38h06a4308_0
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
whoosh                    2.7.4                    pypi_0    pypi
wrapt                     1.14.1           py38h5eee18b_0
wurlitzer                 3.0.2            py38h06a4308_0
xarray                    2022.11.0                pypi_0    pypi
xerces-c                  3.2.3                h780794e_0
xlrd                      2.0.1                    pypi_0    pypi
xz                        5.2.6                h5eee18b_0
yaml                      0.2.5                h7b6447c_0
yapf                      0.31.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0
zipp                      3.9.0                    pypi_0    pypi
zlib                      1.2.12               h5eee18b_3
zstd                      1.5.2                ha4553b6_0
```

---

After reading a little more documentation from the [ISRIC web coverage service](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/373455/i-cant-get-soilgrid-image-with-python-owslib) page, I ran the script again by changing the `version` to `'1.0.0'` (on the second line) as shown in the documentation.

```py
wcs = WebCoverageService('https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/clay.map', version = '1.0.0')
```

That doesn't return any errors, but it downloads a 587 octet `.tif` file (in less than 0.1 seconds) that obviously doesn't contain any data and can't be opened without returning a `None` element in python (opening it with a basic image viewer doesn't work either).

Answer (score 1):

Try using a URN to identify the CRS, e.g.:

```py
response = wcs.getCoverage(
    identifier = ['clay_0-5cm_mean'], 
    crs = 'urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326',
    bbox = bbox, 
    resx = 0.1, resy = 0.1, 
    format = 'image/tiff')
```

Besides that, it would be recommendable to consider whether a datum ensemble is appropriate for your use case. The [GDAL manual](https://gdal.org/user/coordinate_epoch.html) advises against its use:

> The generic EPSG:4326 WGS 84 CRS is also considered dynamic, although it is not recommended to use it due to being based on a datum ensemble whose positional accuracy is 2 meters, but prefer one of its realizations, such as WGS 84 (G1762)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I tried but it still downloads an empty image (587 o). I don't think the data I am trying to download changes much over time, and for my specific application the varying accuracy won't be an issue.